Re-enable the GNOME Power Profile service
I was testing auto-cpufreq in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I installed it using:
git clone https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq.git
cd auto-cpufreq && sudo ./auto-cpufreq-installer

I have removed it using:
sudo ./auto-cpufreq-installer --remove

But it appears that the Gnome Power profile (that used to show and control the options Performance/Balanced/Power Saver) is removed in the process. How can I get it back?

The Gnome Power profile can be accessed by installing the power profiling daemon.
sudo apt-get install power-profiles-daemon

Then it needs to be enabled with systemcli:
symtemcli enable power-profiles-daemon

